# Python virtualenv conflicting

Tags: python, ubuntu-12.04, virtualenv

I'm trying to learn `Django`, so I started by reading about `virtualenv`.

```
sudo pip install virtualenv
```

After this i ended up with:

```
virtualenv at /usr/local/bin/virtualenv
```

and

```
virtualenv-2.7 at /usr/local/bin/virtualenv-2.7
```

If I use *virtualenv-2.7* it seems to work fine, but if I use *virtualenv*, new modules get added to /usr/local/bin, instead of being inside the environment.

#### Example

```
cd ~
virtualenv v1
source v1/bin/activate
easy_install yolk
which yolk
# /usr/local/bin
```

If I use virtualenv-2-7, yolk gets installed correctly inside v1.

Did I mess up the installation? How can I fix this?
Thanks for any help!

#### Edit:

I figured i have two `easy_install` bins

```
/usr/bin/easy_install-2.7 and /usr/bin/easy_install

easy_install --version
distribute 0.6.24dev-r0

easy_install-2.7 --version
distribute 0.6.24dev-r0
```

so this may be the cause of problem? More info:

```
python version: 2.7.3
virtualenv version: 1.10.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`easy_install` should be coming from your virtualenv `v1/bin`

Type `which easy_install`

If it still says `/usr/bin/easy_install` you haven't activated the virtualenv

Comment: Yes, but why i have two easy_install bins? and two virtualenv bins?

Comment: One points to your default version of python. The other is used if you need to specifically pick a python version e.g. if you have both python 2.6 and 2.7 installed.